# url/state changes not working after angular.copy called in a factory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm at my wits end on this one, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I've been making an angular/node/mysql app for the past few weeks and came across this issue. I have a database running mysql that stores a list of users and their information. I created an API to provide the front-end with access to user data for login and all that. The flow is as follows:

User enters new state where info on them needs to be preloaded:

```
.state('info', {
        url: '/info',
        templateUrl: 'views/info.html',
        controller: 'InfoController',
        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['user', function(user) {
                return user.loadInfo();
            }]
```

The code is run in the user factory so that data is fetched before the page loads:

```
app.factory('user', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth) {
    var user = {};

    user.loadInfo = function() {
        var userId = auth.currentUser();
        return $http.get('/users/' + userId).success(function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, user);
        });
    };

    return user;
}]);
```

The page loads fine the first time. Then I navigate somewhere else via $state.go('home') or something, and when I try to return to the same page (/info) it sometimes doesn't work. What happens is I enter in the new url, and the browser basically ignores it and just shows the url of my current page.

1. Start at localhost:8080/#/home
2. Type in localhost:8080/#/info and go there
3. Works fine first time. Navigate to localhost:8080/#/home
4. Now at localhost:8080/#/home
5. Type in localhost:8080/#/info, and the browser ignores it, just displaying localhost:8080/#/home

I've tried commenting out angular.copy, and that seems to fix the issue, but I still need to copy the data over that I fetch from the server (which does successfully get transferred).

**So my primary question is:** Is there an alternative to angular.copy that I can use that will work here? I still find it weird that it is used in all the examples but is causing this issue here.

**Secondary question:** If angular.copy is the way to go, have any of you seen this issue and have a guess at what's causing it? Does something look off in what I'm doing?

**Bonus Info:** I don't know how quite to describe this, but sometimes if I wait long enough before going back to the problem url, it works... I notice that a call is made to the server right as I'm typing in the problem url (before even hitting enter) and when that happens, it seems work. It's intermittent though, and stops any $state.go() calls from working to that problem url if they are called through a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got the answer for this one and it's pretty dumb. "user" is an object inside of the factory and "loadInfo" is a function attached to user. When I did the angular.copy(), data from the server overwrote the loadInfo function so I couldn't use it again...

So yeah, that's solved.